# Getting empty string with self.request.get()

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, post, jinja2

I've got this simple code:

```
import jinja2
import webapp2


JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {}
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

class PostHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.out.write("name = " + self.request.get('name'))       

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/post', PostHandler)],
                            debug=True)
```

**index.html** is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% autoescape true %}
<html>  
  <body>

    <form>Name:
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </form>
    <br>

    <form method = "post" action = "/post">    
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Entering some text in the TextField:

[image]

I can´t get the text from the TextField:

[image]

Someone know what can be my problem?

**EDIT:**

Problem solved with Daniel Roseman answer:

```
<form method = "post" action = "/post">   
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @DanielRoseman you should wait some minuts to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you've got two separate `form` elements, one with the input field and one with the button. But those need to be in the same form.